# Align text on the same line without float

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align text on the same line without using `float` as it is not supported by the `html2pdf converter` that I am using.

The code looks as follow:

```css
.text1 {
    padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
.go-right {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
 <div class='text1'>
    Bill to: <span class="go-right">text</span> <br/>
    Amount:  <br/>
    Date: 
 </div>
```

If I change the `display` to right, the text is aligned to the right side, however, on a separate line, which is not the wanted outcome.

Comment: Do you need `text ` to be on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply add a fixed width to the `span` and adjust the value as you need:

```css
.text1 {
    padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
.go-right {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width:calc(100% - 70px); /*Replace with fixed value if calc not supported*/
}
```

```html
<div class='text1'>
    Bill to: <span class="go-right">text</span> <br/>
    Amount:  <br/>
    Date: 
 </div>
```

You can also consider padding-left to push the content :

```css
.text1 {
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.go-right {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class='text1'>
  Bill to: <span class="go-right">text</span> <br/> Amount: <br/> Date:
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

As both method above are not well supported by the converter you may consider a classic table structure like this :

```css
table {
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill to:</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Amount:</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date:</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I get `'CSSTerminalFunction' object does not support indexing`, so maybe this is not well supported by the converter.

Comment: @filtfilt try to replace calc() with simple value and see if it works

Comment: @filtfilt and what if you simply add padding-left ?

Comment: The text still refuses to move and is moved to the right when `display` property is set to block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161689/discussion-between-filtfilt-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could set the position to absolute and position your go-right that way.  For example

```
.go-right {
text-align: right;
width:100px;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Jsfiddle link also - https://jsfiddle.net/subhojit/r9x3Ln2o/

CSS:

```
.text1 {
   padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
   text-align: left;
 }
.go-right {
   margin-left: 2%;
   width: 5em;
   text-align: left;
   display: inline-block;
 }
.left-texts {
   width: 3.5em;
   text-align: left;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class='text1'>
   <span class="left-texts"> Bill to: </span> <span class="go-right">First Text</span> <br/>
   <span class="left-texts"> Amount: </span> <span class="go-right">200</span> <br/>
   <span class="left-texts">Date: </span> <span class="go-right">10-01-2018</span> <br/>
</div>
```